# Item-list inside of a JSON-object?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am having a little problem.

Inside my MongoDB-collection, I have following record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a77186e8b26df363d40195"),
    "email" : "mail@mail.com",
    "password" : "password123",
    "fullName" : "Ola",
    "interests" : ["football", "baseball"],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to parse out the "interests"-part, but when I try the following code

```
var data = user;
console.log(data.interests);
```

...i just receive "Undefined".
When I try to to console.log(data) I receive:

```
{ __v: 0,
  interests: [ "football", "baseball" ],
  fullName: 'Ola',
  password: 'password',
  email: 'mail@mail.com',
  _id: 58a77186e8b26df363d40195 }
```

Is there anyone who can see the problem? Im really new to this. I am using Node.JS

**UPDATE**
This is the function that sends the data-object through a callback:

```
  try {
    decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);

    User.findOne({
    email: decoded.email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true, user);
        }
    });

  } catch (e) {
    callback(false);
  }
```

Comment: what happens when you use bracket notation `console.log(data["interests"])`

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data[0])`

Comment: Two reasons : either you have `JSON string` instead of  `JSON Object` or you are having `array of object` instead of direct `object`.

Comment: Could you please provide a code where you are retrieving the record from the db and logging it?

Comment: Thanks for replies!

Comment: Output of console.log(data["interests"]) is undefined.

Comment: Output of console.log(data[0]) is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where problem is coming. I used your obj to run code its working fine (except that you are getting it from database, I am assigning directly, but thats not a problem).

```js
var obj={
    "_id" : "58a77186e8b26df363d40195",
    "email" : "mail@mail.com",
    "password" : "password123",
    "fullName" : "Ola",
    "interests" : ["football", "baseball"],
    "__v" : 0
}; //I removed ObjectId() because of error: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined",
 for(var k in obj)
{
console.log(obj[k]);
}
//or directly doing it
console.log(obj.interests);
```